# difference SHA256 C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php

I can't modifiy script  C#.
I have and make the  2 strings in PHP same like C#.

But the two Hash are differents. ( UTF-8 two side.)

i don't how hash C# with array ?, could you help me please ?

en C#

```
//Create a HMACSHA256 routine that uses the key bytes as the encryption key
        var temp = "/gggg";
        var strIntegratorKey = "1f09ae15-017a-4806-bcd6-825532123455";
        var timeStamp = "20210114124401";
        var utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false);
        var keyBytes = utf8.GetBytes(strIntegratorKey.ToString().ToLower());
        string signature;
        using (var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
        {
            var signatureBytes = utf8.GetBytes(String.Concat(temp, timeStamp));
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(signatureBytes));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(signature);
```

C# OK : rdSay3xHElJh7xQj6l4LFYniVVVPVSwc46jpoXY+y8o=

en php

```
$testKey="1f09ae15-017a-4806-bcd6-825532123455";
$testkey1 =utf8_encode(strtolower($testkey));
$bytes = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($testkey1); $i++){
    $bytes.= ord($testkey1[$i]).";";
}
$keyToBytes=$bytes;
echo $keyToBytes."<br>";
//result
$keyToBytes = 49;102;48;57;97;101;49;53;45;48;49;55;97;45;52;56;48;54;45;98;99;100;54;45;56;50;53;53;51;50;49;50;51;52;53;53;

$exemple="/gggg20210114124401";
$text=utf8_encode($exemple);
$bytes = "";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++){
    $bytes.= ord($text[$i]).";";
}
$signatureBytes=$bytes;
echo $signatureBytes."<br>";
//result
$signatureBytes = 47;103;103;103;103;50;48;50;49;48;49;49;52;49;50;52;52;48;49;
$hm=hash_hmac("sha256",$signatureBytes,$keyToBytes ,true);
$hm64=base64_encode($hm);
echo $hm64."<br>";
``
```

PHP :brvlMd5OrT1BQlrdJKfo5qXJrx7ihpa3BIUn1x8w0us=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building a string of the form `"digit;digit;digit;digit;..."` for no reason and use it as the input for `hash_hmac()`. This means you provide completely different inputs for the `hash_hmac()` function than the C# version of your code do. The C# version uses the data directly.

You have to do the same for PHP as well without changing the input. The code will look like this:

```
$testKey="1f09ae15-017a-4806-bcd6-825532123455";
$message = '/gggg20210114124401';
$hm=hash_hmac("sha256", $message, $testKey,true);
$hm64=base64_encode($hm);
```

This will generate the expected hash in `$hm64`:

```
rdSay3xHElJh7xQj6l4LFYniVVVPVSwc46jpoXY+y8o=
```